# Can $ y(t)=\left((t-1)^2+1\right)\cdot \cos(t) $ be a solution for this ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been asked if
$$
y(t)=\left((t-1)^2+1\right)\cdot \cos(t)
$$
can be a solution for the ODE:
$$
y''+y+(y-\cos(t))P(t,y,y') = 0
$$
when $P$ is smooth.

So I concluded that there exists a unique solution to the ODE, by Peano's theorem if:
$$
y_{1}=y,\quad y_{2}=y'.
$$
Then the ODE is of the form:
$$
y_{2}'=-y_{1}-P(t,y_{1},y_{2})(y_{1}-\cos(t)).
$$
$P$ is smooth and a function of $y_{2}$ and $y_{1}$, therefore the ODE has a unique solution, but I don't know how to continue any further.  Any help/hints would be appreciated!

Comment: FYI the only time you need to use `\left(...\right)` is when something is too big for regular `(...)`.  So $(t)$ looks the same whether you use `\left(t\right)` or `(t)`, but $\left((t-1)^2+1\right)$ looks better as `\left((t-1)^2+1\right)` than as `((t-1)^2+1)` - $((t-1)^2+1)$.

Comment: I've been using an editor to be honest hahaha.. do you have a recommendation for a good one?

Comment: I always type everything out, I've found it's faster once you get the hang of it.  Back to your question, your ODE seems to be missing an equals sign.

Comment: Fixed it, it should be =0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $\bar{y}(t)=\cos(t)$ is the $\textit{unique}$ solution of the considered IVP
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
y''+y+(y-\cos(t))P(t,y,y') = 0,\\
y(1)=\cos(1),\quad y'(1)=-\sin(1).
\end{array}
\right.
$$
We remark that the function $y(t)=\left((t-1)^2+1\right)\cdot \cos(t)$ satisfies the same initiale conditions, so it can't be a solution of the EDO.

Answer (score 1):

For a hint:

Compare the roots of $y'' + y$ and $y - \cos(t)$ for your given function $y$.

Comment: I have checked the Value of the suggested solution with t=0, and i got a True statement when I Placed t=0 , y0  and y0'' in the ODE, does it conclude the problem? :S

Comment: I got (suggested solution)
y(0) = 2 , 
y''(0) = 0
 which satisfies the ODE

Comment: If you get a true statement for one value of $t$, you cannot say that you proved that $y$ can be a solution to the ODE. On the other hand, if you can show that the equality cannot hold for one value of $t$, then you have proven that $y$ cannot be the solution of the ODE. So try to find a $t$ such that you get a false statement, independent of $P$.

Comment: I think I got it, I placed t=pi/2, which makes y''+y =2-2pi 
and -P ( y-cos(t)) = 0, Which is a false statement.
So in general If I Proove that for some value t, the suggested solution doesn't hold, then It disprooves that it can be a solution for the ODE?

Comment: That is correct.